# Ford Focus "hot in start" fuse for dashcam

Tags: focus, fuse, dashcam

I have a 2018 Ford Focus and want to install a dashcam that turns on when I start the engine and off when.. you get it.

the diagram is like this: http://knigaproavto.ru/shemy/en/ford/focus/570-20102018-ford-focus-mk3-fuse-box-diagram.html

I used fuse 61 figuring that it is not always on, however, the power is not interrupted even when the car is locked.

do you have any suggestions ?

Thank you,
Florin

Answer (score 1):

Use fuse 85 to supply a relay that then powers the camera, that way the fuse 85 only needs to supply a triggering current not the full current required by the camera.

Use fuse 61 to supply the relay to power the camera.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer! however, I'm a little noob at this, and I'm not 100% sure what you mean. can you please expand a little?

Comment: have a look at : https://www.12voltplanet.co.uk/relay-guide.html

Comment: cool, so basically use fuse 85 as on/off button and fuse 61 as power supply. awesome! thank you!